# Subversion/Tortoise/.NET: merge not copying in newly added file

Tags: .net, tortoisesvn, merge, svn

I've created a branch to handle some new developments I don't want impacting on the trunk until they're complete.

Initially I simply created a copy of the trunk. I then created working copies of both the trunk and the branch.

In the working copy of the trunk, I modified a couple of files and added a new one. I then committed my changes.

I then merged from the trunk to the working copy of the branch. The modifications came through okay but the new file didn't appear. Interestingly, the modifications to the csproj file did work so Visual Studio thinks the file should be there, even though it isn't!

Did I do something wrong, or does the merge functionality not handle new files?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the new files. Look in the repository browser to see if the file does indeed appear. Also make sure that you're merging correctly. i.e. if you merge down in a lower branch (ex: FroYo\fooapp\foolib) and your file resides in another branch (FroYo\fooapp\fooforms), you won't get it. Also if you're merging a specific range of revisions, and that range doesn't include your new file, then you're not going to see it. 
So re-merge, start higher up (if needed), merge by range, VIEW LOG, and make select the rev (or range of revs) that include your commit. Should do it.

Comment: Pure magic. It didn't occur to me that the file addition hadn't comitted properly, but a quick look in the repository showed that it hadn't. Not sure why that happened, but committing the trunk a second time fixed the problem.

Thank you very much.